# How can I get the previous and next link hrefs from a list of hrefs?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that checks for click events on links inside of the 
element with id = menu:

```
$("#menu")
   .on('click', 'a[href^="/City"]', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#editLink').attr("data-href", link);
});
```

The HTML that this code works on looks like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="/City/0101004H">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="/City/0101004I">2</a></li>
   <li><a href="/City/0101004J">3</a></li>
   <li><a href="/City/0101004K">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have two links on another part of my screen as below:

```
<a id="prev" href="#">Prev</a>
<a id="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

How can I make it so that if a user clicks on the "2" link then these links are changed to:

```
<a id="prev"  href="/City/0101004H" title="City 1">Prev</a>
<a id="next"  href="/City/0101004J" title="City 3">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use do like :

```
$("#menu").on('click', 'a[href^="/City"]', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if(jQuery(this).text() == 2) { // this check is not required if this functionality is required for any 'a' under #menu
      jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('li:first').find('a').css('color','yellow');
      jQuery(this).closest('ul').find('li:last').find('a').css('color','pink');
      $('#prev').prop('href', $(this).parent().prev().find('a').prop('href')).prop('title','City 1').css('color','red');
      $('#next').prop('href', $(this).parent().next().find('a').prop('href')).prop('title','City 3').css('color','green');
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/34jj3/)

Update:

```
jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('a') // this will give prev a 

jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('a') // this will give next a
```

[2nd Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/UahMH/1/)

Comment: An `a` element doesn't have a value attribute, and therefore no `val()` method. Use `text()`.

Comment: @mprabhat - Thanks for the correction. Did you see I also added another part to the question?

Comment: by different did you mean to change the first and last a in ul and also prev and next ? I just updated my answer

Comment: @mprabhat - I'm sorry but there's a problem. You hardcoded in the numbers :-(   I was giving the list of address links and as an example I used just four. In practice there could be any number of links. This is what is making it difficult for me as I do not know how to find the next and previous when there's a long list of links.

Comment: But your second fiddle still checks if it is 2. What if the user clicks on 1,2 or 4? In fact there could be up to 100 links. Is there a way I can make it work without hardcoding. 2 was just for example purposes. Thanks

Comment: I mentioned that in my comment, see if this is fine with you,http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/UahMH/2/

Comment: Hi, but you still have things hardcoded. For example it always shows city 1 and city 3. What I need is that when you click on a link then the prev and next button href and title need to change to point to the previous and next links. Thanks

Comment: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/H6A6T/2/) will make prev and next href as next and prev a of the current a and will make there title City + Prev/Next text, whereas [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/H6A6T/3/) will make both href and title of prev and next as prev and next a of current a, as in your given example there is no title to any a hence you wont see any title